# Big Cartel cart

Tags: themes, cart, bigcartel

I have made a custom theme on big cartel, and everything is perfect, except one thing. 
I would like to have the cart update without going to the cart page when adding an item to your cart.
I have made my custom template over the "sexy" theme and have no idea how I go about implanting this

I know this can be done, because default themes like "Good Vibes" do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below.  I didn't include the code for the restoreButton function in the addItem callback but I'm sure you get the idea.  You'll also need your own means of retrieving the product ID based on however you're displaying your product options.  Make sure to also include a reference to Big Cartel's javascript api.

```
$('#add_to_bag').click(function(evt){
    var productId;
    if($('.options_select').length != 0)
        productId = $( ".options_select option:selected" ).attr('value');
    else
        productId = $('.price_options input').attr('value');

    var quantity = $('.quantity input').attr('value');        
    Cart.addItem(productId, quantity, function(cart) {
        $('#add_to_bag').attr('value', 'Item Added');
        setTimeout(restoreButton, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take advantage of the javascript API: https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#javascript-api

With this, you can drop in the line of code to load the API into your theme and have access to add, update, and remove items from the cart using javascript.

Comment: Ive seen this, but I just don't know how to implant it
I add the script and thats all?

Comment: You'll need a decent amount of javascript knowledge to be able to implement this. The first step is adding in the API code, next you'll need to code in more javascript to handle add items when the button is clicked. The code provided in the help manual is just a start.